# FullCalendar - ümlaut in Week View Title

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, title

Has anyone run into this strange issue?

I can't seem to override this formatting in FullCalendar.io.

I am simply looking to use a dash ("-") rather than the ümlaut 'W'.

Current code is as below:

```
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
lang: 'en',

views: {
    agenda: {
        minTime: '06:00',
        maxTime: '19:00'
    },
    week: {
        titleFormat: 'MMM D YYYY'
    },
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found you can set the separator yourself like this:

```
titleRangeSeparator: "-"
```

Just add it at the end of the options and it should work.