# Fullcalendar week view has unrecognized character

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am developing a calendar for SharePoint that allows to connect to multiple calendars from SharePoint and external calendars and show it all in one calendar. I am using the fullcalendar plugin for this and have the following problem when I select the week view:

Internet explorer 11:
[IE #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tQ8Y.png)
(I cannot add more than one link, but in view source it also just shows as a rectangle)

Chrome 48.0.2564.82 m:
As I cannot post more than one link, in chrome it looks like a diamond with a question mark in it, also in view source.

In the month view and day view I do not have a problem (as there is no separator required).

SharePoint also adds the meta-tag in the head for utf-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Thanks,
Jochim

Comment: potential duplicate of 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259866/fullcalendar-%C3%BCmlaut-in-week-view-title' even though slightly different

Comment: inspect the html and css for that element....  make sure all font files are being loaded. Could be caused by numerous things all requiring research in browser dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue myself by using the following option in your fullcalendar code:
titleRangeSeparator: " - "

Was not easy at all to find this in the documentation (or at least for me)